# Retelling of Adam and Eve story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, religion

My dad is trying to find a short story he read in the '80s, possibly in OMNI magazine, which was a retelling of the Adam and Eve story. The story is mostly the same as it appears in the Bible, except that when God discovers that they have eaten from the tree of knowledge, he is not angry, but happy to find that he has finally created a creature smart enough to disobey him. He then casts Adam and Eve out of the Garden of Eden, not as a punishment, but because they are now ready to inhabit the real world.

Google has not been helpful with searching "omni magazine adam and eve", which makes us think it may have been some other similar publication.

Comment: Hi! Please see [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) to help improve this.

Comment: Thank you for offering this guide, but this is really all the detail that I have. It's not a particularly complicated story, which I admit might make it harder to track down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Final Version"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64374), a short story by [John Morressy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Morressy), first published in [*Rod Serling's The Twilight Zone Magazine*, January 1982](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60169+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Twilight_Zone_v01n10_1982-01_noads#page/n74/mode/1up); reprinted in the 1984 anthology [*100 Great Fantasy Short Short Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178021) edited by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), [Terry Carr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Carr), and [Martin H. Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_H._Greenberg).

> "At last!" the Creator cried into the silence. "At last!" He cried again, and the darkness lifted. A joyous light shone forth from His countenance and illumined all around the man and woman and embraced them. "Over and over, on worlds beyond numbering, I have created you. On every world I put you to a test. And of all who take the test, none has yet had the courage to accept the consequences. Eat the fruit, and you can become as I. They could not bear this. When I faced them, they crawled before Me, and cringed, and whimpered for mercy. I demanded guilt and shame, and they gave it to Me, and they live in thrall to it forever. But you gave me Courage."
>
> He stepped closer, and held out His arms. They came to Him, and He enfolded them in light and pressed them to Him. "On a million million worlds I have slaves and worshipers," He said softly. "But here, at last, I have My children."

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!